# Разобрать файл и достать из него нужные данные

Tags: файлы

Вообщем, есть файлы .qm - файлы квеста из игры "Космические Рейнджеры".
Есть редактор этих квестов, есть отдельный проигрыватель, есть даже софтина что бы тексты от туда вытащить. Но ни откуда не получается нормально достать связи между локациями квеста. Связи(пути) отображаются в редакторе, но как я понимаю, они отрисовываются в imageBox или типа того. 
Может кто-нибудь подскажет умную мысль как получить эти связи? 
т.е. сами пути я могу получить, но какие локации он связывает - нет.

Прикладываю квест и инструментарий. 
http://dropmefiles.com/ZsFUI

PS. Авторам игры написал, но пока ответа от них не слышно(
Как я понял игра давно ушла в community, а моя цель будет лишь популяризировать игру. Так что против никто быть не должен.

Comment: В вашем вопросе не видно вопроса. Это скорее предложение поисследовать неизвестный формат файла без документации.

Comment: "Может кто-нибудь подскажет умную мысль как получить эти связи? "

Comment: Но вообще, да. Вы, наверное, правы.